# Y values not plotted in the correct X position - Pandas Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Im new on PANDAS and MAtplotlib, still learning each day. Appreciate your help. I keep receiving for some plots the Y values at the wrong X position. Not sure if there is somethign related to the dataframe im producing, everything looks fine for me, but it keeps plotting at an offset of X+1. As im using DATES for X values, it keeps plotting the values one month ahead everytime.

The dataFrame dfExec1 comes from the main df:

```
dfRevenue = pd.read_csv('Revenue Report_DataHistory.csv')
dfExec1 = dfRevenue[dfRevenue['PLAN/EXEC'] == 'EXEC']
dfExec1.loc[:,'Year'] = pd.to_datetime(dfExec1['Year'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce')
dfExec1 = dfExec1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Year', freq='M')).sum()
```

This is a picture of dfExec1 :

[dfExec1 frame. All data are floats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOXYi.png)

Now i tried to choose to work only with the columns i wanted and zeros as NaN. I also created a new column for the DATES to try to see if the plot came out correct.

```
dfServicos = dfExec1.iloc[:, [0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11]]

dfServicos[dfServicos==0] = np.nan
dfServicos['DATAS'] = dfServicos.index
#dfServicos
fig6, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,7))

#for coluna in dfServicos.columns:
    #ax.scatter(x=dfServicos['DATAS'], y=dfServicos.loc[:,  coluna], s=100, label=[coluna])
ax.scatter(x=dfServicos.iloc[0,11], y=dfServicos.iloc[0, 0], s=100, label=['Fishing'])

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

This is Exec1 after treatment:
[DataFrame - needed to cover blue data but Floats and NaN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETrUo.png)

I only plotted one column as example, but all the plots are showing like this :

[X position offset by 01 month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgaKo.png)

Thank you very much for your support !

Comment: Without knowing what `dfExec1` is we can't really say what the problem might be....

Comment: Thank you, Jody. dfExec1 is just the Basic data where there are some columns which I removed so I could work better the data. I will add a screen shot as well. Thank you.

Comment: Don't add images of code/data/error messages. Instead, post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces your problem. Data , for instance, might look similar in the printout but are different data types leading to different behavior of the code.

Answer (score 0):

just got the problem solved by plotting xticks first. After that needed to configure date format.

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

dfServicos = dfExec1.iloc[:, [0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11]]

dfServicos[dfServicos==0] = np.nan

#dfServicos
fig6, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(35,7))

ax.set_xticks(dfServicos.index)
for coluna in dfServicos.columns:
    ax.scatter(x=dfServicos.index, y=dfServicos.loc[:,  coluna], s=100, label=[coluna])

#ax.bar(x=dfServicos.index, height=dfServicos.loc[:, 'Fishing'])

dateForm = DateFormatter('%m-%Y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dateForm)

formatter = ticker.FormatStrFormatter('$%1.2f')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```